# Line breaks in Statusbar

Tags: haskell, pango, gtk2hs

I have a program here that uses the GTK Status bar and I'd like to have multi-line output in it. When I try to output multiple lines into it, I get glyphs instead as seen below:

[image: glyphs]

I'd expect it to work like in emacs:

[image: noglyphs]

After some searching, I discovered [layoutSetSingleParagraphMode](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pango-0.12.5.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Pango-Layout.html#v%3alayoutSetSingleParagraphMode) which seems to do exactly what I want. The default setting is False for most widgets and we're not setting it ourselves anywhere which makes me think that Statusbar defaults to single paragraph mode.

My problem is that I have no idea how to go from `Statusbar` to `PangoLayout` upon which I can use this function.

The closest I have come was finding [widgetGetPangoContext](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.12.5.7/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#v%3awidgetGetPangoContext) which then let me get `PangoLayout` with [layoutEmpty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pango-0.12.5.3/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Pango-Layout.html#v%3alayoutEmpty) but as the name suggest, this seems to just create a separate `PangoLayout` which doesn't affect the statusbar when manipulated: pushing or popping of text behaves as it did before this.

Is there a function I'm missing? Admittedly, `gtk2hs` swims in a sea of type-classes to emulate OO which doesn't contribute to the readability of the generated docs. It seems that it should be a simple task.

If we're never meant to get out a `PangoLayout` from existing widget then how can I achieve what I want? There seems to be no option to choose the paragraph mode at Statusbar creation time.

See [this](https://github.com/yi-editor/yi/issues/478) for a GitHub issue for this project relating to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

Use `statusbarGetMessageArea` to get the `Gtk.Box` where the status bar's text label is.

Then get the text label with `containerGetChildren <status bar message area>`. This function returns a list of `Gtk.Widget` with just one element, the label.

Cast the widget to a label with `castToLabel`.

Now you can set multi line mode with `labelSetSingleLineMode <label> False`.

Set the label's contents with `labelSetText` or `labelSetMarkup`.

I have tried it with success (gtk 0.12.5 from Hackage, using GTK2, haven't tried it with GTK3).

Comment: You are a beautiful person.